# Code won't write to CSV file Python3, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

My program for getting Crypto price data won't write to the CSV file Python3. It reads just fine and there are no errors, but it won't write to the file.
I have tried the section by itself without all the other stuff, and it works, but for some reason when I put it in here it just won't write any data to the CSV.

Code:
(the 'if time =' sections is to get the price every 15 mins, and to close the script at 6:50 to prepare for daily system reboot)

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
import csv


try:
    requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ping').json()
except:
    print("Connection failed")


time = str(datetime.now().time())[:5]



def get_data():

    time = str(datetime.now().time())[:5]
    print("\n\nTime: " + time + '\n')

    with open('BTCAUD_data.csv', mode='r') as BTCAUD_data:
        reader = csv.reader(BTCAUD_data, delimiter=',')
        data = list(reader)[-1]

    previous_buy_price = data[6]
    previous_sell_price = data[8]

    print(previous_sell_price)
    print(previous_buy_price)


    data = requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr', {"symbol": "BTCAUD"}).json()

    raw_price_change = data["priceChange"]
    print(raw_price_change)

    price_change_percent = data["priceChangePercent"]
    print(price_change_percent)

    weighted_avg = data["weightedAvgPrice"]
    print(weighted_avg)

    last_price = data["lastPrice"]
    print(last_price)

    last_qty = data["lastQty"]
    print(last_qty)

    bid_price = data["bidPrice"]
    print(bid_price)

    bid_qty = data["bidQty"]
    print(bid_qty)

    ask_price = data["askPrice"]
    print(last_price)

    ask_qty = data["askQty"]
    print(ask_qty)

    open_price = data["openPrice"]
    print(open_price)

    high_price = data["highPrice"]
    print(high_price)

    low_price = data["lowPrice"]
    print(low_price)

    trading_volume = data["volume"]
    print(trading_volume)

    quote_volume = data["quoteVolume"]
    print(quote_volume)


    with open('BTCAUD_data.csv', mode='w', newline='\n') as BTCAUD_data:
        writer = csv.writer(BTCAUD_data)

        writer.writerow([bid_price, ask_price,'\n'])
        writer.writerow([previous_buy_price, previous_sell_price, raw_price_change, price_change_percent, weighted_avg, last_price, last_qty, bid_price, bid_qty, ask_price, ask_qty, open_price, high_price, low_price, trading_volume, quote_volume])



def main():

    time = str(datetime.now().time())[:5]

    if time == "6:50":
        exit()

    if time[3:] == "0":
        get_data()

    if time[3:] == "15":
        get_data()

    if time[3:] == "30":
        get_data()

    if time[3:] == "45":
        get_data()


    sleep(60)


        
while True:
    main()
```

Comment: your code contains a lot of stuff that has nothing to do with writing to a file. Please remove this noise and post an absolute minimum of what is necessary to reproduce the problem

Comment: thats the point, when the code is just what is required to write the file, it works fine, but with the other things added in, it won't work. Nevertheless, I will try to consolidate it while retaining the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every time you open a file with mode "w" you completely overwrite it. Might it be that you want to use "a" to append instead?
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 1):

Just open the file and then save the data frame as a CSV file for example

```
data = {'column': 'row1',
         'column2': 'row1',
         'column3' : 'row1',
         'day': 'day',
         'hour' : 'hour',
        }

    df=pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv('twee.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the module csv in Python, but I have some experience with Pandas.
You can do

```
import pandas as pd
```

then you can read the file with `dataset=pd.read_csv(filename)`

You can do all the manipulation on your dataset and then save it with `dataset.to_csv(output_filename)`